# mysql:best way to optimize this sql query

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

i want to get best way to get result from this query

here is my tables instructrue

**schools**

```
CREATE TABLE `schools` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user` mediumint(5) NOT NULL,
 `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `number` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `address` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
 `admin` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `admin_phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `admin_email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `school_phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `learn` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `mr7la` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `sfof` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
 `fswl` smallint(3) NOT NULL,
 `json` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`),
 KEY `status` (`status`),
 KEY `learn` (`learn`),
 KEY `mr7la` (`mr7la`),
 KEY `number` (`number`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**3agz**

```
CREATE TABLE `3agz` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `school` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `tkss` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `teacher_7ess` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `teacher_master_7ess` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `time_added` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `reported` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `fixed` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `info` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `school` (`school`,`tkss`,`teacher_7ess`,`fixed`),
 KEY `school_2` (`school`),
 KEY `tkss` (`tkss`),
 KEY `reported` (`reported`),
 KEY `time_added` (`time_added`),
 KEY `school_3` (`school`,`time_added`),
 KEY `school_4` (`school`,`fixed`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=85 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

here's SQL Fiddle for this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3313e0/4

---

you can see her's my sql query i use

```
SELECT
    schools.* , ( select count(id) from 3agz where 3agz.school = schools.id and fixed = 0 ) as has_3agz
           FROM
                schools
           WHERE
                ( select count(id) from 3agz where 3agz.school = schools.id and fixed = 0 ) > 0

limit 10
```

the explain is

schools => PRIMARY                      : ALL

3agz    => DEPENDENT SUBQUERY           : ref

3agz    => DEPENDENT SUBQUERY           : ref

here's i ask can i do this and what's the best way

1 - can i get ignore second sub query on where and get it depended on first sub query in select

2- if number 1 answer is you can't
   can i ignore the first sub query  [ has_3agz alias ]
   after this query executed i loop trow the result [schools ids]

and make second query like this

as example the first query return school ids  1 , 2 , 3 , 4

```
select school , count(id) from 3agz where school in ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ) and fixed = 0
```

the attach every count to it's school in array

hope you understand me

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT schools.*, count(*) as has_3agz from schools
LEFT JOIN 3agz on 3agz.school = schools.id and fixed = 0
GROUP BY schools.id;
```

Comment: Think to do what the OP wants (ie, ignoring items with a count of 0) would either need `HAVING has_3agz > 0` if you need a LEFT JOIN, or probably just change the LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Thank you @Kickstart for your comment , i already use having because manager can query  has_3agz > 0 :)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I missed the part about skipping those with 0. The right way to do it would be just to change it to an inner join if you want to skip 0s, or use having if you want another condition on the count.